# Call DataTable AJAX explicitly with server side processing

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using datatables in my angular application with server side processing which is working fine for me.

my datatable having following options

```
  options = {
    sDom: 'rt',
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
      this.http
        .post(
          this.url,
          dataTablesParameters
        ).subscribe(( resp : any) => {
          resp = resp.json();
          callback({
            recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
            recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
            data: resp.data
          });
        });
    },
    columns: [
      { data: "id" },
      { data: "firstName" },
      { data: "lastName" }
    ],
    scrollY: `calc(100vh - ${$("#header").height() + 85}px)`,
    scroller: { loadingIndicator: true , displayBuffer: 2 },
  };
```

if you can see, there's an `ajax` property with two parameters `datatableParameters` and `callback`. Is there any way that I can call the ajax property of datatable explicitly, like if I click any button in web page, then it should come over the ajax function with both the parameters I have mentioned with it. Because I want to make http call with the `callback` function and `datatableParameters`.

In my case I'm using server side processing with scroller, when I scroll it is calling ajax function with both the parameters. I want the same with my explicit button click event. Something like control should come back to the same ajax function in datatable options when I click to a button. Is it possible, either with jQuery or something else.

Comment: You can call fnDraw method of dataTable for refreshing table and call ajax.

Comment: Which exactly controls you would like to implement? That AJAX option has success feedback which you're not allowed to modify or trigger in any other way than through certain DataTables api methods (to draw table with modified paging, sorting, filtering parameters). So, most probably, you should trigger those parameters changes rather than AJAX call itself.